# delete in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i am write this stored procedure to delete one row

```
       DELIMITER $$

      CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spr_StdDelete`(IN ID INT)
      BEGIN


      DELETE FROM students WHERE ID=id;


      END
```

but when i call it from php its delete all table

```
     $result = mysql_query("Call spr_StdDelete('$ID')")
     or die(mysql_error());
```

then i try this sp but its not working

```
      DELIMITER $$
      CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spr_StdDelete`(IN ID INT)
      BEGIN
      DELETE FROM students WHERE ID=@ID;
      END
```

plz help ...

while when i use this query its delete the selected row

```
      $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM students WHERE ID=$ID")
      or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Just so you know, your `DELETE FROM students WHERE ID=id;` query is the same as writing `delete * from students;`

Comment: yes i am change it to be DELETE FROM students WHERE ID=@id ;
but still not work

Comment: @Phil, you're right, although in this case, the server resolves the ambiguity by assuming you are comparing the local variable to itself, since local variables are case insensitive and have precedence over column names when there's more than one possible interpretation.  Same net result, if the variable isn't null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spr_StdDelete`(IN STUDENT_ID INT)
  BEGIN

  DELETE FROM students WHERE id=STUDENT_ID;

  END
```

Comment: thnx its working done

Comment: “A local variable should not have the same name as a table column. If an SQL statement, such as a SELECT ... INTO statement, contains a reference to a column and a declared local variable with the same name, MySQL currently interprets the reference as the name of a variable.” — http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/local-variable-scope.html